Sharing a publisher between threads?
Are publishers thread safe?
Can I share a reference to a publisher with another thread and use it from that thread to publish a message, or do I need to create a new node + publisher in the thread and spin it in order to publish on a topic?

Does this answer your question? is rospy.Publisher.publish() thread safe?

Deciding from the source code of the Publisher, ROS 2 publishes messages through rcl_publish().
This function is thread-safe as you do nothing else with the publisher simultaneously, like trying to dispose of it in one thread while publishing from another.
Deciding from this answer, creating publishers from different threads is also safe. Destroying publishers may be less so, but in the majority of cases, the publisher, once created, does not need to be destroyed before the whole application shuts down.
